# Poor wifi strength after taking apart laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, hardware-failure

[image]

Wifi connection has been very poor since I took apart my laptop.  These two loose cables are right next to the onboard wifi chip - there seems to be some relationship between how they're positioned and how the wifi works, but I can't really pinpoint anything.  Anyone tell me what these are, how they should be hooked up?  I am pretty sure they were loose when I started taking it apart, at most pressed up against something.

**edit - more pics:**

[image][image]

Comment: How were those cables positioned before they were not loose...

Comment: They were folded up, together, tucked under the top-right corner of the mobo, by the left side of the red cable's sleeve.

Comment: Look around the wifi card for small, round metal connectors that those two disconnected cables would connect to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those connectors form an antenna with the laptop display. There's an antenna that generally loops around the inside of the display unit. This forms a fairly large wifi antenna that is better at picking up weaker wifi signals. With those wires you currently have only extremely high energy signals can be picked up. You need to find a way to reconnect those wires to the loop inside your display unit. If you could share a larger photo of your motherboard that would be great.

Comment: Updated with two more pics.  One of them is of the bottom side of the motherboard, with the onboard wifi.  I suspect these cables are supposed to go into those two black rectangular bits?

Comment: You got it!  Reconnected and signal strength is way back up.  Eternal thanks.